# Get concrete value in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Let me explain my problem,
in Pentaho Report Designer I want to build such a report, where I have one data set, i.e. one request to database

```
SELECT code, name FROM EMPLOYEES
```

and show result of this request not in the form of list, but put every result in appropriate place. i.e. like in below picture 
[image]
Where field "code" is unique, just one result can be put into red label in picture.

How can I do this in Pentaho Report Designer?

I can solve this problem by creating 3 data set, for each of caption. But what if captions like this will be much more, creating requests for each of this caption will not be so effective.

Hope I could explain my question.

Comment: Have you tried using the `subquery` feature of prd ?? I think you need to place three subqueries and each subquery will fetch the required dataset.!!

Comment: thank u @Rishu , for your comment. But, can u plz explain how to do it or give some links, I couldn't find any subqueries in prd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I got it right, but If you want to use the values returned by your query, you could create a new formula called "your_formula":

```
 =MULTIVALUEQUERY("name_of_your_query")
```

This will give you an array with the result of the query. Then you could use another formula to get the 1st result of the array. For example:

```
 =ARRAYLEFT([your_formula])
```

and get the first result of your query. This way let you use your_formula as parameter. This means you can drag and drop it on your report and use it.

I hope it helps.

Regards,
Tatan.

Comment: Hi, Sebastian. Yes. I've searched something like this. But, ARRAYLEFT function returns just first element of an array, there is no way to set any condition to filter from array

Comment: Well, ARRAYLEFT was an example, but you can use: `=ARRAYMID([your_formula];3;1)` to select an specific position at the array. About filtering to set a condition I would try:
`=IF(ARRAYMID([your_formula];3;1) = 'something', 'if true', 'if false');`

I hope it helps.
Regards